# Hiding Google reCAPTCHA v3 with different code / disclaimer text

Tags: css, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, divi

My name is Zach and I manage some websites that use Google reCAPTCHA v3 to protect a contact form. Many of these sites use the Divi theme builder. I would like to hide the badge icon in the lower right corner of the screen on all webpages of each website and add some text as a disclaimer below the contact form on each website.

I've referred to the [reCAPTCHA FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq) and other forum posts where this is discussed but it seems like the explanation doesn't really cover how much and in what ways we are allowed to modify exactly what is displayed on the FAQ page. So I'm curious if the below method of hiding the badge and adding the disclaimer sounds like a good approach to you all, or is there a missing piece based on what you are aware of?

Based on my understanding of what is allowed, here is how I would accomplish hiding the badge:

1. I would add the following code to the custom CSS of the site:

   .grecaptcha-badge {
   visibility: hidden !important;
   }

I'm aware that the !important tag is not present in the documentation, but in order to hide the badge on the page with the contact form, the !important is necessary. It seems like omitting the !important tag will not hide the badge on the page with the contact form.

2. In addition, just on the page with the contact form, I would add the following text to the bottom of the footer:

"Google reCAPTCHA used.   [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en) and   [Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en) apply."

Note that the badge icon normally is visible on all the webpages of each site, not just the page with a contact form.

We would also like to translate the above disclaimer in the footer into Spanish and Portuguese for use on our Spanish and Portuguese websites.

I'd love to hear if you think this method will work and whether it fulfills all legal obligations based on what you are aware of?

Thanks,

-Zach

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at recaptcha enterprise or the invisible recaptcha implementation?

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Either should let you hide recaptcha being used and then you can stick a warning where-ever you like on your page.